# Testing ember components with promises

Tags: testing, ember.js, sinon

I've hit a wall in testing an ember component.

I have component that has an action

pseudocode

```
actions: {
   doSomething(){
       this.set('showSpinner', true);
       this.model.serverOperation().then(()=>{
           this.set('showSpinner', false); 
           this.service.doSomething();        
       })
   }
}
```

in my test, i would like to assert that `showSpinner` is true when the action is invoked, then becomes false after the promise resolves.  So my test looks like (pseudocode, using ember-sinon-qunit):

```
const deferred = Ember.RSVP.defer();
const modelMock = this.mock(this.model);
const serviceMock = this.mock(this.service);

modelMock.expects('serverOperation').returns(deferred.promise);
serviceMock.expects('doSomething);

this.$('selector').click(); // invokes 'doSomething'

assert(this.showSpinner, true)

deferred.resolve();

assert(this.showSpinner, true)
```

the problem is, on the `deferred.resolve()` call, the last assert fires before the `then` method in the component.

Is there a canonical way to handle this sort of thing in ember?

I tried using async to test, but in that case a few interesting things happen:

1. I change the final assert to execute in a `setTimeout`, and then the assert on `showSpinner` passes, but
2. the test still exits before `then` runs (so before the timeout callback fires), and since we are using ember-sinon-qunit, the test harness fails on the `serviceMock` expectation.

Answer (score 0):

Put the last assert in a `then()` after call to `deferred.resolve()`

```
deferred.resolve();

deferred.promise.then(()=> {
    assert(this.showSpinner, true);
});
```

Comment: that doesn't help the sinon failure.